# Complex subsetting and merging of arrays Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array that is 9 columns. I need to be able to make subsets of columns and then generate a new array that is just the subsets (for example merging 0:3 and 6:8). Getting the individual subsets is easy, but I'm stuck on creating a new array.

```
Cmatrix =np.array([ (1,    1,   0,    1,     0,    0,  1, 0,  1),\
                    (1,   -1,   0,    1,     0,    0, -1, 0, -1),\
                    (1,    0,   1,    0,     0,    1,  1, 0,  1),\
                    (1,    0,   1,    0,     0,    1, -1, 0, -1),\
                    (1,    0, 0.5,    0,     0, 0.25,  0, 1,  1),\
                    (1,    0, 0.5,    0,     0, 0.25,  0, 1, -1),\
                    (1,  0.5, 0.5, 0.25,  0.25, 0.25,  1, 0,  1),\
                    (1,  0.5, 0.5, 0.25,  0.25, 0.25,  1, 0,  1),\
                    (1, -0.5, 0.5, 0.25, -0.25, 0.25, -1, 0, -1),\
                    (1, -0.5, 0.5, 0.25, -0.25, 0.25, -1, 0, -1)])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Cmatrix =np.array([ (1,    1,   0,    1,     0,    0,  1, 0,  1),\
                    (1,   -1,   0,    1,     0,    0, -1, 0, -1),\
                    (1,    0,   1,    0,     0,    1,  1, 0,  1),\
                    (1,    0,   1,    0,     0,    1, -1, 0, -1),\
                    (1,    0, 0.5,    0,     0, 0.25,  0, 1,  1),\
                    (1,    0, 0.5,    0,     0, 0.25,  0, 1, -1),\
                    (1,  0.5, 0.5, 0.25,  0.25, 0.25,  1, 0,  1),\
                    (1,  0.5, 0.5, 0.25,  0.25, 0.25,  1, 0,  1),\
                    (1, -0.5, 0.5, 0.25, -0.25, 0.25, -1, 0, -1),\
                    (1, -0.5, 0.5, 0.25, -0.25, 0.25, -1, 0, -1)]
interesting_cols = range(3) + range(6,8)
new_matrix = Cmatrix[:,interesting_cols]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
np.hstack((Cmatrix[:, :3], Cmatrix[:, 6:8]))
```

Comment: Joran Beasley's answer is better I think. If you have matrices of differing origins to glue together then `hstack, vstack, dstack` are best.